# Remove all line breaks at the beginning of a string in Swift

Tags: string, swift

I have a string like this:

```
"

BLA
Blub"
```

Now I would like to remove all leading line breaks. (But only the ones until the first "real word" appears. How is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 71, accepted):

If it is acceptable that newline (and other whitespace) characters are removed from *both ends* of the string then you can use

```
let string = "\n\nBLA\nblub"
let trimmed = string.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
// In Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3):
let trimmed = (string as NSString).stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
```

To remove *leading* newline/whitespace characters only you
can (for example) use a regular expression search
and replace:

```
let trimmed = string.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("^\\s*",
    withString: "", options: .RegularExpressionSearch)
```

`"^\\s*"` matches all whitespace at the beginning of the string.
Use `"^\\n*"` to match newline characters only.

Update for **Swift 3 (Xcode 8):**

```
let trimmed = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "^\\s*", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

Comment: @ConfusionTowers This will also trim trailing line breaks and leading and trailing spaces.

Answer (score 20):

You can use `extension` for Trim

**Ex.**

```
let string = "\n\nBLA\nblub"
let trimmed = string.trim()

extension String {
    func trim() -> String {
          return self.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    }
}
```

Comment: This will also trim trailing line breaks and leading and trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

###Swift 5.5

```
let trimmed = content.trimmingCharacters(in: NSCharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
```

Answer (score 0):

The trimming function wasn't working for me but this works. I am just replacing the next line "\n" with a blank space

```
func removeNextLineString(name: String) -> String{
    var newName = name
    newName = newName.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: " ")
    
    return newName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 / Xcode 14.2:

```
extension String {
    func removeNewLines(_ delimiter: String = "") -> String {
        self.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: delimiter)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let string = "Hello World\nHello World"
print(string)
/*
Prints
Hello World
Hello World
*/
print(string.removeNewLines())
/*
Prints
Hello WorldHello World
*/

print(string.removeNewLines(" "))
/*
Prints
Hello World Hello World
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using...

```
let trimmed = string.components(separatedBy: .newlines).joined()
```

because `trimmingCharacters(in: .newlines)` didn't seem to work for my purposes

Answer (score -1):

This will remove all leading new lines (carriage returns)

```
extension String {
    func trimLeadingNewLines() -> String {
        guard let firstIndex = indices.first, let lastIndex = indices.last else { return self }
        let firstCharIndex = self.firstIndex(where: { !$0.isNewline }) ?? firstIndex
        return String(self[firstCharIndex ... lastIndex])
    }
}
```