# Print String using variadic params without comma, newline and brackets in Swift

Tags: swift, swift2

While I was trying to use Swift's `String(format: format, args)` method, I found out that I cannot print the formatted string directly without newline(`\n`) and brackets being added.

So for example, I have a code like this:

```
func someFunc(string: String...) {
    print(String(format: "test %@", string))
}

let string = "string1"
someFunc(string, "string2")
```

the result would be:

```
"test (\n    string1,\n    string2\n)\n"
```

However, I intend to deliver the result like this:

`"test string1 string2"`

How can I make the brackets and `\n` not being printed?

Comment: See if [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28957940/remove-all-line-breaks-at-the-beginning-of-a-string-in-swift) can help you out.

Comment: You should rename `string` to `strings` to make it clearer that it's an array, not a string.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? `"test %@"` has only *one* format specifier, how would you print two strings using that format?

Comment: @MartinR I intend to print the elements inside the array

Comment: `String(format: ...)` takes a format string and a variable list of arguments. For each argument there must be a format specifier. In your case, the format has only *one* format specifier, so only one argument is printed, no matter how many arguments you pass. – Therefore: Is your question "How to pass a variable argument list to String(format:...)?", or is your real question "How can I print a variable list of strings?"

Answer (score 2):

Since `string` parameter is a sequence, you can use `joinWithSeparator` on it, like this:

```
func someFunc(string: String...) {
    print(string.joinWithSeparator(" "))
}

someFunc("quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog")
```

Comment: Will this also implicitly remove the new line characters?

Comment: @SArnab Judging from OP's example, `"\n"`s are not part of the strings, so there is no need to remove them.

Comment: Ah I see, they're being added during print. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will first need to concatenate your list of input strings, otherwise it will print as a list, hence the commas and parentheses. You can additionally strip out the newline characters and whitespace from the ends of the string using a character set.

```
var stringConcat : String = ''
for stringEntry in string {
    stringConcat += stringEntry.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
}
```

Then just print out the stringConcat.