# Removing line breaks from string

Tags: ios, swift

I have a string like so:

```
var aString = "This is a string \n\n This is the second line of the string\n\n"
```

Which inside a textview looks like so:

```
This is a string 

This is the second line of the string


// 2 extra lines of unnecessary white space
```

But i want it to look like this:

```
This is a string 
This is the second line of the string
```

I want to remove all "\n" from the end of the string and remove \n where it repeats itself so theres no white space in the middle.

ideally, I'm guessing the end result should be this:

```
var aString = "This is a string \n This is the second line of the string"
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at replacing the `/n/n` with just `/n` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200888/any-way-to-replace-characters-on-swift-string or even `/n/n ` with `/n` to get rid of the additional space. Though that might be a bit simplistic

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28957940/remove-all-line-breaks-at-the-beginning-of-a-string-in-swift

Comment: Are you sure it's not `\n`?

Comment: @Sulthan yeah sorry it is \n

Answer (score 10, accepted):

what about this?

```
var aString = "This is a string \n\n\n This is the second line of the string\n\n"
// trim the string
aString.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.newlines)
// replace occurences within the string
while let rangeToReplace = aString.range(of: "\n\n") {
    aString.replaceSubrange(rangeToReplace, with: "\n")
}
```

Answer (score 15):

The basic idea for your code would be replacing all double `\n` with a single `\n`.

```
var aString = "This is my string"
var newString = aString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n\n", with: "\n")
```

Comment: I was going to say the same thing but you beat me to it.

Comment: problem is, `\n` still sits at the end of the string if there is an `\n` there, so I get an extra empty line at the end of the string when displaying inside the textview

Comment: I mistyped. Replace the /n parts of my code with \n. It should work, no way it doesn't.

Comment: It does work but only to an extent - lets say the string is `"This is a string \n\n\n"` - it will return `"This is a string \n\n"`. Also, if the \n sits at the end of a string, i want it removed.

Comment: You'll need to have the code in a loop, which runs until \n\n can be found in your string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var aString = "This is a string \n\n This is the second line of the string\n\n"

let components = aString.components(separatedBy: "\n\n").filter { $0 != "" }
print(components.joined(separator: "\n"))

// prints expected output with a single line separator
```