# How to remove \n\n from UITextView using swift code?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4, uitextview

I let user to enter text into UITextView then I send it to firebase using this code

```
         func sendDataToFirebase(){
            
              let productID = self.ref.childByAutoId().key
              let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
           
              let product = [ "productID" : productID,
                              "uid" : userID,
                              "details": self.txtProductDetails.text! as String
        
                ] as [String : Any]
       
            self.ref.child("products").child(productID!).setValue(product)

           }
```

If the text that user enter has multiline, it will go to firebase and has \n\n
[image]

So when I fetch the text I am getting the same result of \n\n. How can I remove \n\n where the textView have to look organized.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing line breaks from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43073073/removing-line-breaks-from-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Try This*

```
  func sendDataToFirebase(){
        
          let productID = self.ref.childByAutoId().key
          let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
          guard let text = self.txtProductDetails.text else{return}
          let newText = text.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n\n", with: "")
       
          let product = [ "productID" : productID,
                          "uid" : userID,
                          "details": newText
    
            ] as [String : Any]
   
        self.ref.child("products").child(productID!).setValue(product)

       }
```

Comment: `guard let text = self.txtProductDetails.text else { return }` this is pointless. `UITextView` text property  will NEVER return `nil`.

Comment: Yes, but it's good practice to safely unwrap the optional when you see one.

Comment: Good answer. One issue. If */n/n* is replaced with "" then all of the spaces where /n/n should/could be are lost. So reading back it would look like *months to make.The Size* (no space between the "." and "The"). Probably better to add a space " ". Just a thought.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But the text image has space before \n\n (like large and medium \n\nThe weight). So, I thought it would structure better without space.