# Swift - String removal code not performing as expected

Tags: swift, string, macos, prefix

I'm working on a macOS Swift-app where I need to perform folder/file traversal. In this specific instance, I need to remove the first part of a file path...i.e., if a file has the path of `MyFolder/MyItem`, I need it to just read as `MyItem` for display purposes.

Based off the responses in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28957940/remove-all-line-breaks-at-the-beginning-of-a-string-in-swift/28958785#28958785), I wrote the following code:

```
if fileString.hasPrefix("/") {
    fileString.remove(at: fileString.startIndex)
    print(fileString)
}
```

...where I remove any part of the `fileString` before and including "/".

However, this doesn't seem to work in practice....`MyFile/MyItem` doesn't get changed to `MyItem`, it remains as `MyFile/MyItem`.

Comment: The code you posted would change `/MyFile/MyItem` to `MyFile/MyItem`. Why do you expect your code to remove a `/` in the middle?

Comment: Swift doesn't modify your string, I believe it creates a new one. Try var s = (your line) and then see what s has

Comment: @rmaddy I see, makes sense. How would I then remove "/" and whatever is before it?

Comment: use the substring after getting the index of the /. Just remember Swift does copy-on-change

Comment: Actually, the `remove(at:)` method is a mutating function: it _will_ modify the value of fileString in-place, without requiring you to re-assign the variable. In fact, the return value of that method is _not_ the modified string, but the character that was removed from the string. Copy-on-write is an important concept in Swift but it's not really relevant to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can locate the first (or last) slash character and remove 
everything from the beginning of the string up to and including 
that separator, for example:

```
var fileString = "My Volume/My Folder/My Item"
if let r = fileString.range(of: "/", options: .backwards) {
    fileString.removeSubrange(..<r.upperBound)
}
print(fileString) // My Item
```

But if your intention is to extract the file name (last path component)
for display then there is a dedicated method for that purpose:

```
let fileString = "My Volume/My Folder/My Item"
let displayName = FileManager.default.displayName(atPath: fileString)
print(displayName) // My Item
```

Another method is

```
let fileString = "My Volume/My Folder/My Item"
let baseName = URL(fileURLWithPath: fileString).lastPathComponent
print(baseName) // My Item
```

which is similar to the previous one, but does not localize the
file name.