# iOS Swift UILabel Display Two Lines into Single Line

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uilabel

In my app I'm facing one trouble, my requirement is I want to show text in single line, but response which was coming from API is like:

```
"Hi
Hello
How Are You"
```

How to convert this and display in single line in `UILabel`

Comment: replace occurrence of new lines. Refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28957940/remove-all-line-breaks-at-the-beginning-of-a-string-in-swift?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var newString = myString.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines).joined(separator: " ")
```

Then you can bind that newString to UILabel.